# Strange violin-like sound from refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator, appliances

I'm noticing an occasional noise coming from my refrigerator that sounds almost like someone is playing a violin that is badly out of tune. I did some research into refrigerator noises, but I can't find any description of a matching sound. I notice it happening maybe once every few hours. (It might be happening more than that, but I don't always notice it.)

Here is an audio clip: https://sndup.net/wj6b/

It's coming from the back of the refrigerator on the freezer side, about 3/4 of the way up from the bottom.

My refrigerator is a Frigidaire Gallery model FGHS2631PF4A. I'm guessing there's a component failing.

Comment: You might take a look to see if there's an access panel you can remove, or find service docs on line. An "out of tune violin sound" strikes me as being a belt slipping. It may be that the compressor is belt driven and the belt is slipping now. It could be as simple as a belt replacement.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a motor moving. all Refridgeration compressors in residential units are sealed units direct drive. It may be a form of defrost where the compressor is dead headed to create heat and defrost. Other than that is there an ice maker?

Comment: If your unit has a icemaker, the sound might also be caused by a blockage or defect in the motor or geartrain which rotates the shaft to push newly-frozen ice cubes into the ice cube tray.

Comment: Probably just a leprechaun  practicing up for St. Pat's day.

Comment: sounds like either a noisy fan bushing ... or a servo motor trying to move, moving a bit and retrying

Comment: It does have an ice maker. The ice maker seems to be operating normally, and I don't hear the violin sound when I hear the ice cubes pushed into the tray. (They seem to happen at different times.)